# Gcloud Compute - VMs keeps terminating

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I just created a vm on gcloud with cli tools. But I could not connect it since it is terminating itself immediately after starting. While creating it, I have followed an article which is related with "nested virtualization" published by gcloud. A few seconds after when I started it, it is waiting and terminating itself. I got an error code  and it is "Code: '-3220096401196114372'

Comment: please read this before posting; [ask], [mcve]

Comment: there is no enough information or details, can you provide the gcloud command used? which document did you follow? you mention "nested virtualization", can you specify where you did create your instance ? How did you enable it ?

Comment: Hi, I just issue this [1] command and it was executed with no error.
The document is [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances)

`[1] gcloud compute instan': gcloud compute instances create os-pod-1 --zone europe-west4-c --image nested-virt-cnt7-image-1 --min-cpu-platform "Intel Skylake" --boot-disk-device-name=nested-cnt7-pod-1 --boot-disk-size=40GB`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue solved by itself after Gcloud team has solved a problem on US datacenters.

Since, I do not have a support plan on gcloud I've raised a ticket on billing team by mistakenly and they forward my ticket to techncal team. A crew member said this issue could be related with a known issue on US datacenters. I basically delete and recreate my vm on EU datacenters and it worked.